# What are the difference between $(document).bind('ready', function) and $(document).ready(function() {})

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I want to upgrade from requirejs version 2.0.0 to 2.1.5

Here is the code:

```
define(['jquery', 'test.js'],
    function ($, test) {
    var test = new $.test({
        //options
    });
    ....
});
```

test.js

```
(function($) {
    var registerEvents = function() {
        //dosth
    };
    $.test = function(options) {
        $(document).bind('ready', function() {
            registerEvents();
        });
        ...
        return test;
    }

    ...
});
```

In version 2.0.0, requirejs holds the dom ready event till all resources are downloaded, so it worked correctly https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/249

When I upgrade to requirejs version 2.1.5, the registerEvents function will never be called.

But supprisingly, if I change:

```
$(document).bind('ready', function() {
    registerEvents();
});
```

To:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    registerEvents();
});
```

It worked fine

So my question is: What are the difference between them?

Edit: I am using jQuery v1.7.2

$(document).on('ready', function(){}) not working

Comment: To everyone answering that there's no difference, can you explain why she got different results? Maybe requirejs treats them differently, even if jQuery itself doesn't.

Comment: @Barmar the `.bind()` method is deprecated, and `.on()` is its replacement. `$(document).ready(function() {` is a shortcut for `$(document).on("ready", function() {`

Comment: FYI from [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/): *"There is also `$(document).on( "ready", handler )`, **deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.**"* But if they actually *removed* it, I don't see anything saying that in the docs.

Comment: @mangseth: `bind` is deprecated, not *removed*.

Comment: *"I am using jQuery v1.7.2"* ***Why?!?!?!***

Comment: The difference is, as [the docs say](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) `This behaves similarly to the ready method but if the ready event has already fired and you try to .on( "ready" ) the bound handler will not be executed.`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know, I said deprecated. I don't know why it's not working in her case. I just noted she shouldn't be using it anymore anyways.

Comment: @mangseth When was `bind` deprecated? Can you provide a link?

Comment: @blgt, that looks like the answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: The project is quite old

Comment: `As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements.` As I read it now, it's not deprecated, just not "preferred" then.

Comment: https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Upgrading-to-RequireJS-2.1 check this link.

Comment: At the time of posting your question, RequireJS 2.1.15 is already out. You should upgrade to 2.1.15 version rather than 2.1.5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is, as [the docs say](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

> There is also $(document).on( "ready", handler ), deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. This behaves similarly to the ready method but **if the ready event has already fired** and you try to .on( "ready" ) **the bound handler will not be executed.** Ready handlers bound this way are executed after any bound by the other three methods above. *[em mine]*

`.bind` and `.on` behave similarly.

---

This is the only difference between

```
$( document ).ready( handler )
$().ready( handler ) // (this is not recommended)
$( handler )
```

and

```
$( document ).on( "ready", handler )
$( document ).bind( "ready", handler )
```

that's mentioned in the docs, so I'm guessing is the most likely source of your issue