# Is window.addEventListener("load", init); faster than $(function () { init(); });?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like the title says.

I'm the front-end guy at my company and one of the back-end guys uses JavaScript while I use jQuery. I know there are strong opinions on either side of the fence and I'm not trying to start a battle here, I am just curious.

To me, it doesn't seem like it makes much of a difference, except that the JavaScript function starts at window load, whereas the jQuery function starts at document load.

Comment: Note that jQuery **is** JavaScript. When you use jQuery, you're using JavaScript, in other words. And as to the question, "faster" is not the comparison to make. The "ready" event that triggers the jQuery version is fired *before* the "load" event, so the jQuery version will run first. Whether that's good or bad completely depends on what's going on with your code.

Comment: `$(function () { init(); });` could be rewritten as `$(init);`, the anonymous function does nothing useful.

Comment: It's worth noting these two are **not** exactly equivalent. The jquery equivalent would be to use `.bind("load"...` Related question (fd that i recall answering): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718996/what-are-the-difference-between-document-bindready-function-and-docume?lq=1

Comment: Thanks for further clarification everyone! @Quentin, I had no idea I could do that! Neat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about pure "when code runs" and ignoring outside variables (i.e. the overhead of including jQuery on a page), the jQuery method would be faster because it fires on the `domcontentloaded` event, which *should* occur sooner than `window`'s `load` event.

Why is it faster? It fires *when the DOM is available* and *before things like images have loaded*. In an image-heavy site, that could be quite a difference in timing. `window`'s `load` event fires after those resources load, which is likely going to occur later (sometimes much later) in your Document's lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, that makes sense. I gave you the green check since you answered first. :)

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you are measuring.

In terms of execution time, it will take longer to load all of jQuery and to run the code through the jQuery function then it will to call a single native method. (How much difference that makes depends on if you are going to be loading jQuery or not anyway).

In terms of when the `init` function will execute, `load` will generally fire a significant time after DOMReady since `load` waits for images, stylesheets, etc to finish loading.

You generally shouldn't be doing performance comparison when changing two variables anyway. jQuery Vs Native is a separate issue to DOMReady Vs Load.

You should also be cautious of [premature optimisation](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)